# What java rule "((CheckBox) v).isChecked())" use?

Tags: java, android

`CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkAutosave);
    checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
        if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked())
          DisplayToast("CheckBox is checked");
        else
          DisplayToast("CheckBox is unchecked");
      }
    });`

What java rule does "((CheckBox) v)" use? 
Is it shortening? how to deconstruct it?
Are there some useful shortening except this one?

Comment: This is the most unclear question for today.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. If you want to know what this statement is doing, its simply a cast.

Comment: You stole my words Maroun

Comment: Could you please post some context? say, 3..5 lines of code on both sides of the snippet that you show?

Comment: Provide more context and I'm sure you'll get plenty of answers

Comment: Sorry, I update it, I only want to know why can use two enclosed to context the view.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't cast a view to a checkbox..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing the context here - something like:

```
public void checkIt(Object v) {
  if ((CheckBox) v).isChecked() {
     System.out.println("checked!");
  }
}
```

The `(CheckBox)` casts the object `v`.

In other words, it asserts to the compiler that `v` has type `CheckBox` and thus it is OK to call the methods of `CheckBox` on `v`.

We have to "know" that `v` is really of type `CheckBox` and not merely `Object` as declared in the method declaration.

Generally, casts like this should be avoided where possible, because we lose compile-time type safety. If `v` is not actually a `Checkbox`, we will get a runtime exception (`ClassCastException`)

The additional parentheses mean we can call the method directly. So instead of

```
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
cb.isChecked()
```

we can do:

```
((CheckBox) v).isChecked();
```

So in that sense, it is a 'shortening', if that's what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there some useful shortening except this one?

If I understand your question you are asking to shortening your code:

```
boolean isToastDisplayed = ((CheckBox) v).isChecked() ? DisplayToast("CheckBox is checked"); : DisplayToast("CheckBox is unchecked");
```

This is by using conditional operator `? :`

> What java rule does "((CheckBox) v)" use?

This is called **Object Type Casting**

Comment: Ternary operator. EDIT: Is another name.

Comment: also known as Conditional Operators, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html